Certain time Inactive in site means i do navigate to login page using session expiry
I do session based navigate the url & session will expiry while user inactive in site as well.
Problem is Inactive certain time means session will expiry and navigate to login page as well. But on that time user open the dev-tool also user active in the dev tool window. but site consider different window so consider user is inactive it will navigate to login page. So, it wrong right
devtool open means session timer should pause
devtool close means session timer should restart
